# Contact Form - getting success message but not sending message

Tags: php, html, forms, submit, contacts

Below is the script I have written for my contact form. When I fill it out to test it, I get the appropriate success message. However, I don't get the sent message showing up in my email.

```
         <?
$action=$_REQUEST['action']; 
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */ 
{ 
?> 
<form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"> 
<strong>Your name *</strong><br> 
<input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
<strong>Company name</strong><br> 
<input name="companyname" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
<strong>Your email *</strong><br> 
<input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
<strong>Your message *</strong><br> 
<textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br> 
<input type="submit" value="Send email"/> 
</form> 
<?php 
}  
else                /* send the submitted data */ 
{ 
$name=$_REQUEST['name']; 
$companyname=$_REQUEST['companyname'];
$email=$_REQUEST['email']; 
$message=$_REQUEST['message']; 
if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message=="")) 
    { 
    echo "Name, Email, and Message are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a>      again."; 
    } 
else{         
    $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
    $subject="Message sent using your contact form"; 
    mail("n.dumanov@gmail.com", $subject, $companyname, $message, $from); 
    echo "Your email has been sent! GovPal will reply within the next 24 hours!"; 
    } 
}
```

?>

Comment: Works for me. Check your junk mail.

Comment: It doesn't appear in spam folder.

Comment: Instead of `mail(...)`, do `$mail = mail(...)`. Then `var_dump($mail);`. What does it say?

Comment: its says:bool(false) Your email has been sent! GovPal will reply within the next 24 hours!

Comment: And I still get nothing in either my spam folder or inbox

Comment: bool(false) means the email was not sent. You need to set it up first. Better open another question for that, or do a search.